# How to map value to sinle id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, database-administration

I have below 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  joveuser varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  timestamp date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  Article int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,timestamp)
);

CREATE TABLE PQR(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  statid int(11) NOT NULL,
  institutionid int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,institutionid),
  UNIQUE KEY statid_2 (statid,institutionid),
  KEY statid (statid),
  KEY institutionid (institutionid)
) ;
```

**Table ABC**

| id | joveuser | timetsamp | article |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2021-02-15 | 85 |
| 2 | def | 2021-04-25 | 113 |
| 3 | ghi | 2021-05-01 | 63 |
| 4 | jkl | 2021-05-28 | 22 |
| 5 | mno | 2021-06-18 | 185 |

**Table PQR**

| SID | statid | institutionid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 3 | 33 |
| 3 | 1 | 44 |
| 4 | 8 | 55 |
| 5 | 9 | 66 |

I want to compare **id** from **ABC** with **statid** from **PQR**. if id is not present in PQR table then it should insert to PQR table with institutionid value '999' along with **id**. For example **id** 4 from **ABC** not present in **statid** from **PQR**, so it should made insert with new row 4,999.

**Sample output**

| sid | statid | institutionid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 3 | 33 |
| 3 | 1 | 44 |
| 4 | 8 | 55 |
| 5 | 9 | 66 |
| 6 | 4 | 999 |
| 7 | 5 | 999 |

Here id 4 and 5 are not present, so it inserted 2 row with id and constant institutionid value.

How can achieve by using query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO pqr (statid, institutionid)
SELECT id, 999
FROM abc
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM pqr
                   WHERE abc.id = pqr.statid )
```

If you create unique index for `pqr (statid)` then the query can be simplified till

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO pqr (statid, institutionid)
SELECT id, 999
FROM abc
```

Comment: I have unique index for statid and institutionid. In second query we need to pass where condition right how id being compared in second query?

Comment: @Moolya *I have unique index for statid and institutionid.* They're absent in shown CREATE TABLE. *In second query we need to pass where condition right how id being compared in second query?* The comparing is performed implicitly while unique constraint is checked.

Comment: @Moolya There is no unique key by `(statid)` in `pqr`.

Comment: Unique key only for statid & institutionid together. for statid and institutionid there is separate index.

Comment: @Moolya Indices are not interesting in this task. Only uniqueness makes sense. Now `statid` may contain duplicates - is it correct?

Comment: yes because same statid may associated with other institutionid as well.

Comment: @Moolya If so then only query 1 or its analog (LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL) is a solution.

Comment: Yes, even I feel query 1 is solution,thanks for help